# My ruby gems path is messed up after switching from RVM to rbenv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I made the switch from RVM to rbenv following this [guideline](https://gist.github.com/brentertz/1384279) and now I can use bundler and run pure ruby, but when I run `bin/rails s`, `bin/rails g model ModelName`, or `rails g model ModelName` I get the below error:

```
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
/Users/home/Development/blogger/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
```

There is also a massive crash report following this, but I have chose not to include it because it is longer than the allowed StackOverflow post length, and I don't think it says anything of value.

I have tried the same thing with ruby 2.1.2 and got the same result.  I have also done `gem install rubygems-update` which runs successfully and `gem pristine --all` which gets this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems ["==all"] >= 0
```

Here is the result of `gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.4 (2014-10-27 patchlevel 265) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/home/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /Users/home/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec
     - /Users/home/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/home/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Under GEM PATHS, why is the path going into 2.1.0?  This is my old version of ruby which I'm pretty sure is not even on my machine any more.  It is not listed under `rbenv versions`.  Is this the problem? How do I change the gem path and what do I change it to?

I set the $PATH in my .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

My .profile is empty, and `echo $PATH` results in:`/Users/home/.rbenv/shims:/Users/home/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

`which ruby` results in `/Users/home/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Another issue is if I try to use the `bundle` command in my home directory I get `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory` 
even though bundler is included in my gem list.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ruby at least three times, and I get the same errors every time.  Once again I believe the problem is with my GEM PATH but I don't have enough experience to know how to fix it.  Thank you.

Comment: The GEM_PATHs are a red herring. Gems for each x.y release of Ruby are stored in the same directory.

Comment: But if I'm using 2.1.2 or 2.1.4 should 2.1.0 be at the end of my GEM_PATH?  I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Comment: Yes it should. That was the point of my comment. I'm using 2.2.4, and my paths have "2.2.0" in all of the places where yours have "2.1.0". Unfortunately I don't know what else is wrong either. You'll need to characterize it more and update your question.

Comment: Okay got it.  Is there any other information you think i should include? This is the guideline I followed to switch from RVM https://gist.github.com/brentertz/1384279

Comment: If you are on osx, it is better to use homebrew packages. There is one for rbenv

Comment: @prusswan I installed rbenv using homebrew (brew install rbenv) is this what you mean?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling / rebuilding all of your gems? you need to do this when you change rubies..

Comment: @Doon I just tried that for the first time using the script here https://gist.github.com/IanVaughan/2902499 and a lot of gems said "default gem can't uninstall" Does this mean some gems are using the system default of ruby, and some are using the version specified by rbenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was just to delete my rails project and start a new one.  I also uninstalled and reinstalled my gems, and did rbenv rehash before creating a new project.  I figured I should post an answer and not just delete the question, because I did not not see delete and remake the rails app in any other responses to the few questions about this error out there.

Comment: looks like your either your rbenv installation or the previous Gemfile/Gemfile.lock was hosed. Good attempt at self-fixing

Comment: @usernm how exactly did you uninstall the gems? I don't think that actually deleting a rails project fixes the problem? I think it's the same as just deleting the vendor folder?

Answer (score 0):

@usernm ... I think you should have a `GEMFILE` in your directory . Problem is pretty confusing . So just try to add `ruby 'version'` on the top line. I hope this is one option to look at . Well example would be:

`ruby '2.1.4'`

Comment: I was missing that, but it made no difference.

Comment: are you using bundle install command to update the gemlist.  you see gem pristine --all is happened when in a new install it finds for the stored gemfile. and if it cant then it start to install it again all of it. so just assure me that you are using bundle install command?

Comment: I'm using bundle install. I just did it agin to make sure.  I still get the gem pristine --all prompt every time

Comment: well... this is last way I think of for now.. one : install stable version of ruby like 2.1.5 then run bundle install if throws error with pristine all then run gem pristine --all in terminal to restore the gems which is not error prone... and this will show which gems cant be restored.... remove them and bundle again... this way you will only left with error gems which needs configuration for last time