# lazy symbol binding failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

Using OS X Yosemite, for an existing Rails project I've installed ruby version 2.3.0 (using rbenv), installed bundler, bundled and rehashed. Now when I try to start the rails server, using bundle exec rails s, I'm getting the error below.

I'm not entirely sure what happened after installing ruby 2.3.0 because this actually happened some time ago and as I couldn't get it to work in time, I switched back for an older ruby version for now. I've been searching for a solution for quite some time now since then. Solutions to similar issues here and other sites didn't solve this problem. The maybe most obvious solution, as stated below, running `gem pristine --all` doesn't solve the problem. I really hope you can guide me through, thanks a lot!

```
-> bundle exec rails s
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.5
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring pg-0.18.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.18.4
Ignoring puma-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.4.0
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.6.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.4
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_data_object_alloc
  Referenced from: /Users/nandersen/Projects/the-lunch/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_data_object_alloc
  Referenced from: /Users/nandersen/Projects/the-lunch/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

**Update**

This is an update for a suggestion from an answer. The following error is the same for all mentioned gems.

```
gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems ["binding_of_caller"] = 0.7.2
```

Comment: i had same problem with a student who chmod 777 too much ,i've sorted it out with  the dumb lazy way : complete suppression and reinstall of all  components : rvm, ruby , all gems mysql and psql .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've tried a lot to get rid of this error, I cannot exactly tell what eventually solved it - but on the way to the solution I found out that I maybe had installed rbenv via github pull as well as homebrew. Assuming that this could lead to not installed gems (under a specific ruby version) being claimed as installed, this seems like a possible explanation. After running `rm -rf ~/.rbenv`, while leaving the brew's rbenv version installed, cleared the "ignoring ...  because its native...." hints while reinstalling the gems.

The installation problem of the `pg` app was solved by resetting the correct config path:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

and then running `bundle`

Answer (score 0):

Try following the hints in the error messages:

```
gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.5
gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
gem pristine pg --version 0.18.4
gem pristine puma --version 3.4.0
gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've added the result to my question @Uri Agassi.

Comment: The other calls pass?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, the error is the same for all of them.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387192/my-ruby-gems-path-is-messed-up-after-switching-from-rvm-to-rbenv

Comment: Thanks for the link. As the answer mentions deleting the rails project, I think the result is the same if I just delete the vendor folder, which I already did. It would be interesting how exactly he removed the gems. I tried with `rm -rf ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0` and reinstalled the version but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [Install Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) with `libpq-dev` lib

It looks like you don't have psql drivers

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but as I've stated in my answer, this command doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Linus one more solution in my answer, could you try it

Comment: I'm using the `Postgres.app` for some time now. I've additionally installed `brew install postgresql` but the problem stays. Shall I additionally install something?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of binding of caller says that it **only** works until ruby 2.1

> Only works in MRI Ruby 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0, 2.1 and RBX (Rubinius)

ref:
https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller#user-content-binding_of_caller

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint but this gem is not in the project's gemfile. I'm not sure why it's mentioned in the terminal. What can I do to fix this then? Thanks in advance.